# Ubuntu 18.04 - Windows Manager (Nautilus) search feature is broken

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

I've upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and I am dissatisfied with the search feature in Nautilus. Previousyly, I could press a letter to jump to a folder that starts with this letter and enter it right away but now, in my opinion it's completely ruined. What happens now is that a search field pops up and it filters all items that start with this letter and shows only the found items. It takes a massive amount of time. For example, previously I could press "w" in my folder and it would jump and highlight the first folder/item that starts with "w" and right now it takes a massive amount of time to search for items starting with "w" and filter them. This made my install Double Commander that has this feature. I will never use Nautiuls again.

Comment: Unfortunately, Nautilus has changed a lot with Gnome. I had similar problems too, the better choice for me was to change from Nautilus to another windows manager like **Nemo** or **Dolphin**.